# Python: SyntaxError: 'return' outside of function

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I've searched and read numerous posts about this and read the resolution. Basically what I'm seeing is that it comes down to indentation. I've tried all the recommendations yet I'm still getting the error about 'return' being outside of function. at '**return temp_c, temp_f**' Any ideas?

```
# RasPi Temperature Sensor - Beginning Sensor Networks

#

# For this script, we explore connecting a digital temperature sensor

# to the Raspberry Pi and reading the data. We display the

# temperature

# in Celsius and Fahrenheit.

# Import Python modules (always list in alphabetical order)

import glob

import os

import time

# Issue the modprobe statements to initialize the GPIO and

# temperature sensor modules

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')

os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# Use glob to search the file system for directories that match the

# prefix.

# Save the path to the directory.

datadir = glob.glob('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28*')[0]

# Create the full path to the file

datafile = os.path.join(datadir, 'w1_slave')

# Procedure for reading the raw data from the file.

# Open the file and read all of the lines then close it.

def read_data():

    f = open(datafile, 'r')

    lines = f.readlines()

    f.close()

    return lines

# Read the temperature and return the values found.

def get_temp():

# Initialize the variables.

    temp_c = None

    temp_f = None

    lines = read_data()

# If the end of the first line ends with something other than

# 'YES'

# Try reading the file again until 'YES' is found.

while not lines[0].strip().endswith('YES'):

    time.sleep(0.25)

    lines = read_data()

# Search the second line for the data prefixed with 't='

    pos = lines[1].find('t=')

# A return code of -1 means it wasn't found.

if pos != -1:

# Get the raw data located after the 't=' until the end of the

    temp_string = lines[1][ pos+2:]

# Convert the scale for printing

    temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.00

# Convert to Farenheit

    temp_f = temp_c * 9.00 / 5.00 + 32.00


return temp_c, temp_f

# Main loop. Read data then sleep 1 second until cancelled with CTRL-
# C.

while True:

    temp_c, temp_f = get_temp()

    print("Temperature is {0} degrees Celsius, "

    "{1} degrees Fahrenheit.".format(temp_c, temp_f))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: indentation maters in python

Comment: possible duplicate of [Python indentation issue?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2143291/python-indentation-issue)

Comment: You have `return` outside of a function, just like the traceback says. If you meant it to be in a function, put it into that function. If not, you'll need to do something other than `return`.

Comment: I'm extremely new to Python. I've attempted all manner of indentation or lack thereof. Can you provide more details on exactly what I need to do?

Comment: What's odd is that the code is a direct copy and paste from the ebook I'm reading. Seems odd that it would be incorrect! :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to indent everything after `lines = read_data()` and up to `return temp_c, temp_f`.

```
# RasPi Temperature Sensor - Beginning Sensor Networks

#

# For this script, we explore connecting a digital temperature sensor

# to the Raspberry Pi and reading the data. We display the

# temperature

# in Celsius and Fahrenheit.

# Import Python modules (always list in alphabetical order)

import glob

import os

import time

# Issue the modprobe statements to initialize the GPIO and

# temperature sensor modules

os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')

os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# Use glob to search the file system for directories that match the

# prefix.

# Save the path to the directory.

datadir = glob.glob('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28*')[0]

# Create the full path to the file

datafile = os.path.join(datadir, 'w1_slave')

# Procedure for reading the raw data from the file.

# Open the file and read all of the lines then close it.

def read_data():

    f = open(datafile, 'r')

    lines = f.readlines()

    f.close()

    return lines

# Read the temperature and return the values found.

def get_temp():

# Initialize the variables.

    temp_c = None

    temp_f = None

    lines = read_data()

    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< I INDENTED FROM HERE... <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

    # If the end of the first line ends with something other than

    # 'YES'

    # Try reading the file again until 'YES' is found.

    while not lines[0].strip().endswith('YES'):

        time.sleep(0.25)

        lines = read_data()

    # Search the second line for the data prefixed with 't='

        pos = lines[1].find('t=')

    # A return code of -1 means it wasn't found.

    if pos != -1:

    # Get the raw data located after the 't=' until the end of the

        temp_string = lines[1][ pos+2:]

    # Convert the scale for printing

        temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.00

    # Convert to Farenheit

        temp_f = temp_c * 9.00 / 5.00 + 32.00


    return temp_c, temp_f

    # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<< ... TO HERE <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<


# Main loop. Read data then sleep 1 second until cancelled with CTRL-
# C.

while True:

    temp_c, temp_f = get_temp()

    print("Temperature is {0} degrees Celsius, "

    "{1} degrees Fahrenheit.".format(temp_c, temp_f))
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: That fixed it. I realize indentation matters, but again I'm *extremely* new as I said. This was out of a rpi manual for a temp sensor. Thank you for the assistance. I find it disheartening that the book was incorrect. Yikes. Different problem now, though. I'll have to post a separate thread about that I suppose.

Comment: Are you sure it was incorrect, and that it has a blank line every other line? Is it possible something happened when you copied or pasted it?

Comment: @user340424, remember to upvote good answers, including but not limited to the accepted one. https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers

Comment: Everyone has been upvoted. Can't see it because my rep isn't 15 + yet. Also, there could have been a copy + paste error, but I did paste it into notepad++ to check the indentation. Odd.

Answer (score 0):

```
def get_temp():

   temp_c = None

   temp_f = None

   lines = read_data()

   # If the end of the first line ends with something other than

   # 'YES'

   # Try reading the file again until 'YES' is found.

   while not lines[0].strip().endswith('YES'):

      time.sleep(0.25)

      lines = read_data()

      # Search the second line for the data prefixed with 't='

      pos = lines[1].find('t=')

      # A return code of -1 means it wasn't found.

      if pos != -1:

      # Get the raw data located after the 't=' until the end of the

      temp_string = lines[1][ pos+2:]

      # Convert the scale for printing

      temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.00

      # Convert to Farenheit

      temp_f = temp_c * 9.00 / 5.00 + 32.00


   return temp_c, temp_f
```

Indentation if that helps

Answer (score 0):

Here's a properly indented version of your code. You also had a mixture of tabs and 4-spaces, which should be avoided as it often causes problems.

```
# RasPi Temperature Sensor - Beginning Sensor Networks
#
# For this script, we explore connecting a digital temperature sensor
# to the Raspberry Pi and reading the data. We display the
# temperature
# in Celsius and Fahrenheit.

# Import Python modules (always list in alphabetical order)
import glob
import os
import time

# Issue the modprobe statements to initialize the GPIO and
# temperature sensor modules
os.system('modprobe w1-gpio')
os.system('modprobe w1-therm')

# Use glob to search the file system for directories that match the
# prefix.

# Save the path to the directory.
datadir = glob.glob('/sys/bus/w1/devices/28*')[0]

# Create the full path to the file
datafile = os.path.join(datadir, 'w1_slave')

# Procedure for reading the raw data from the file.
# Open the file and read all of the lines then close it.
def read_data():
    f = open(datafile, 'r')
    lines = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    return lines

# Read the temperature and return the values found.
def get_temp():
    # Initialize the variables.
    temp_c = None
    temp_f = None
    lines = read_data()

    # If the end of the first line ends with something other than
    # 'YES'

    # Try reading the file again until 'YES' is found.
    while not lines[0].strip().endswith('YES'):
        time.sleep(0.25)
        lines = read_data()
        # Search the second line for the data prefixed with 't='
        pos = lines[1].find('t=')

        # A return code of -1 means it wasn't found.
        if pos != -1:
            # Get the raw data located after the 't=' until the end of the
            temp_string = lines[1][ pos+2:]
            # Convert the scale for printing
            temp_c = float(temp_string) / 1000.00
            # Convert to Farenheit
            temp_f = temp_c * 9.00 / 5.00 + 32.00

    return temp_c, temp_f

# Main loop. Read data then sleep 1 second until cancelled with CTRL-
# C.
while True:
    temp_c, temp_f = get_temp()
    print("Temperature is {0} degrees Celsius, "
          "{1} degrees Fahrenheit.".format(temp_c, temp_f))
    time.sleep(1)
```